# How to apply pipeline_smote just on training set in mlr3pipelines?

Tags: r, mlr3

I am working on an imbalanced dataset with a two-class response variable using mlr3. I want to apply SMOTE method to oversample the minority. I learned that this method should be used only on the training set, not on the test set. However, if I do not misunderstand, the mlr3 pipeline manipulates the whole dataset before setting a task during which the dataset is splitted into the training and test sets. I wonder how to apply the SMOTE method (`mlr_pipeops_smote`) only on the training set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is automatically only applied on the training set; see [the documentation](https://mlr3pipelines.mlr-org.com/reference/mlr_pipeops_smote.html):

```
The output during prediction is the unchanged input.
```